# Load two tables from different databases both oracle using SQL-LOADER

Tags: oracle, blob, etl, sql-loader

In my job we use Python to make the ETL's.

So everything was fine until I had to insert `BLOB` values.

The logic we have is like this. We have a select from the database origin (also Oracle) and we save this data into a `.csv` file, then we read this file and with the help of SQLLoader we populate the table in the other database.

I can't do this with a `BLOB` file because when I try to make a

```
select <column1> || ',' || <column2> || ',' || <blob> 
from <table>
```

this statement fails because I can't concatenate the `BLOB` value. So I tried making an insert line per line but it's too slow.

Is there another way I can do this? I don't know if I can make an

```
insert into <table>
select <columns>
from <table_origin>
```

when I had two different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate in the python, not in the SQL, then you can just:

```
select <column1>, <column2>, <blob> from <table>
```